# Controlling I/O Module using python code

Tags: python, io

[image]I'm trying to control a relay board (USB RLY08) using a section of python code I found online (https://github.com/jkesanen/usbrly08/blob/master/usbrly08.py). It is currently returning an error which I'm not sure about.[image] Does anyone have any ideas? I'm not actually needing all the code and instead just wanting to turn a single relay on and off.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. So I downloaded the pyserial-3.4.tar.gz and unzipped the contents. I then tried to run  pip install pyserial from command prompt but I'm getting an error. Anyone any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I added another image above to show the error I'm seeing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error probably because **pyserial** module is not installed on your system. Try installing pyserial package from PyPi index using below command :

```
python -m pip install pyserial
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to install pyserial

e.g. with

```
pip install pyserial
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install pyserial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial.html#installation).